# JavaScript is not connecting with web page for unkown reason

Tags: javascript, html

I have come up with an issue, I am working on something I have been been working on for about 6 hours now and haven't been able to find a solution.
The code for my HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <title>Chore Door!</title>
    <link href="resources/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="header">
      <img src="resources/images/logo.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div class='title-row'>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="instructions-number">1</td>
          <td class="instructions-text">Hiding behind one of these doors is the ChoreBot</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="instructions-number">2</td>
          <td class="instructions-text">Your mission is to open all of the doors without running into the ChoreBot.</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="instructions-number">3</td>
          <td class="instructions-text">If you manage to avoid the ChoreBot until you open the very last door, you win!</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="instructions-number">4</td>
          <td class="instructions-text">See if you can score a winning streak!</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <img src="resources/images/Star.svg"/>
      <p class="instructions-title">Instructions</p>
      <img src="resources/images/Star.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div class="door-row">
      <img id='door1' class="door-frame" src="resources/images/closed_door.svg"/>
      <img id='door2' class="door-frame" src="resources/images/closed_door.svg"/>
      <img id='door3' class="door-frame" src="resources/images/closed_door.svg"/>
    </div>
    <div id="start" class="start-row">Good luck!</div>
    <script src="./script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Due to the link of the JavaScript file I will just put a live to my repository on GitHub:
[Text](https://github.com/claudewill1/claudewill1.github.io/blob/master/DevProject/script.js)

Any help will be appreciated. I have been working with JavaScript for about 3 weeks.

Thank you

Comment: You question don't provide a question!!!

Comment: I probably have just been staring at my screen for too long, but I guess what I really needed was just for someone else to take a look at my code. I have been reading through different questions that have been asked on here, stackexchange, codeproject, and many other sites, none of them suggested any thing about the web developer tools. I am knew to web development. I am not completely familiar with all the tools yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the console log.

The file is connecting just fine, it is just that you have an error in the file and so the code is not running correctly.

> TypeError: Math.Floor is not a function

The name of the method is [`floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) (*lowercase*) not `Floor`

So change `Math.Floor` to `Math.floor` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thank you, this kind of issue has happened to me working with other languages, I always miss something small. and I stated I've only been working with JavaScript for 3 weeks. So I am not completely familiar with all the web developer tools, prior to starting this language I have only worked with desktop and mobile applications in the past prior to 3 weeks ago.

Comment: I fixed that issue, but, the images aren't changing like they should with the onclick events.

Comment: @user3788873 your two `is` functions (*`isBot` and `isClicked`*) try to compare the path you have defined with the `src` property of the images. But the `src` property holds the full path (*like `https://.....`*). To just get the value of the attribute (*not property*) that you set use `door.getAttribute('src') ===` instead of `door.src ===`

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am starting to understand this better than I did earlier.